# Output the strings inside of multiple .txt files in a directory

Tags: java

I have a folder which file name is: "List of names". Inside that folder i have a 5 ".txt" file documents and each document file names is a person's name.

I want to retrieve the five documents and display the strings inside each documents. How do i do this? I tried this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Liarliar {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

        File Galileo = new File("C:\\List of names\\Galileo.txt");
        File Leonardo = new File("C:\\List of names\\Leonardo.txt");
        File Rafael = new File("C:\\List of names\\Rafael.txt");
        File Donatello = new File("C:\\List of names\\Donatello.txt");
        File Michael = new File("C:\\List of names\\Michael.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;

        try{
            System.out.println("Enter a number list of names:");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = scanner.nextInt();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        }catch(IOException e){
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for someones time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following lines are not needed as they are meant to take input from user.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number list of names:");             
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);             
int input = scanner.nextInt();
```

Instead you need to read the files one by one using a FileInputStream or FileReader. See [here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/28.html) for an example on how to read data from files. Do this for each of your files.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more generic to not hard code the names of the individual files like Galileo.txt. You can create a File representing the directory, and then call listFiles to get all the files in the directory, like

```
File nameFile = new File(""C:\\List of names");
File[] personFiles = nameFile.listFiles();
```

Then you can iterate over this File array, and open each file in turn, and read the contents, like

```
for (File person : personFiles) {
    showFileDetails(person);
}
```

where showFileDetails is a separate method you write for opening the file and displaying the information.