# Output each string inside .txt file

Tags: java

Made a program retrieving .txt files from a folder. Each .txt files contains 1 or 2 lines of word. I get the output of each filenames of .txt files from a folder:

```
Donatello
Galileo
Leonardo
Michael
Rafael
```

ex. codes i have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Liarliar {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

        File listofnames = new File("C:\\List of names");
        File[] names = listofnames.listFiles();

        for(File person : names){
            int index = person.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
            if(index>0&& index <= person.getName().length()-2){
                System.out.println(person.getName().substring(0, index));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This are all filenames, but that is not I want to be the output. The output I want is:

```
Donatello 2
Hi
Hello
Galileo 2
Fine
Thanks
Leonardo 1
Hi
Michael 1
Hello
Rafael 1
Hi
```

Explanation: The example output given above e.g. Donatello 2, the number 2 after space and the name Donatello, the 2 correspond to the numbers of words inside the filename Donatello.txt. 2 because there are 2 lines of words. I hope you get my point.

Any help would be greatly much appreciated. Thank you...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output the strings inside of multiple .txt files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481534/output-the-strings-inside-of-multiple-txt-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got your point. 
Donatello(file name) 2(containing line number)
Hi
Hello
(above two lines are content in Donatello.txt, right?

Solution:

If file size is at most two lines, you can generate a new class to meet your requirement:

```
class FileInfo {
String fileName;
int lineNum;
String[] content;
}
```

Then read file line by line to fill information for your FileInfo. At last, print out all information you need.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes that is right exactly my point. Thanks by the way. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you break your code into methods. For example, write a method that takes a `File` as an argument and returns the number of lines in that file:

```
public int countLines(File f) {
    ...
}
```

Then, a method that takes a `File` and writes it's contents to `System.out`:

```
public void writeContents(File f) {
    ...
}
```

And a method that takes a `File` and returns it's name:

```
public String getName(File f) {
    ...
}
```

You can now compose your program from those three functions and some glue code:

```
public void processFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        // Print info for this file using the three functions above
        ...
    }
}
```

This is generally a good way to program. If a problem is hard then try to break it into smaller chunks.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks cameron, I'll try this one.